# How do I hide files from "All My Files" in Mac OS X v10.7 (Lion)

Tags: osx-lion

It should probably come as no surprise that their are certain files I don't want to appear in "All My Files" EVER. How do I get Mac OS X v10.7 (Lion) to ignore specific folders for its "All My Files" feature?

Comment: Put them somewhere else. *runs*

Comment: What part of "all my files" don't you understand? :)

Answer (score 42):

I figured it out. Go the *System Preferences* -> *Spotlight* -> *Privacy*.

Drag in the folders you don't want indexed. They get removed from the "All My Files" feature.

Comment: Awesome reply buddy...Thanks...This was exactly i was looking for

Comment: Hi @gman! Could you accept an answer? I assume this one worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This does not appear to work in Yosemite (10.10) or Mavericks (10.9). At the time the question was asked, Mountain Lion (10.8) was the current operating system at the time.

> This would work, but is a little bit of overkill.
>
> If you Ctrl-Click on "All My Files" in the Finder window, you can edit the search >that "All My Files" does without changing your Spotlight preferences.

Comment: It doesn't include all of the criteria though. You could also edit `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch/search.savedSearch`.

Comment: This does not work. When I Ctrl-Click I don't get an option to edit. I am running Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your files in a folder called `.noindex`, they won't be indexed.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way that I have found in Yosemite is:

1. Go to System Preferences->Spotlight.
2. Click on the Privacy Tab.
3. Under "Prevent Spotlight from searching these locations", Drag your iCloud Drive Folder into the list.

   - Your iCloud Drive is located at Users~{username}~Library~Mobile Documents
   - Any other folders that you do not want to be visible in "All My Files" can also be added to this list.

Optional:

If iCloud drive disappears from the finder sidebar, you can re-enable it if desired by:

1. Open a Finder Window.
2. Click Finder->Preferences.
3. Check "iCloud Drive" under Favorites

Now you should still have a link to the iCloud drive in the Finder sidebar and the contents of your iCloud drive will NOT show up under "All My Files"

Comment: How is this any different than gman's answer four years earlier?

Comment: Who mentioned iCloud?